# Why the same object looks different in render / solid view?

Tags: modeling, rendering

Why it looks different in render / solid  view? No modifiers etc. [image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was a bump on the material!

Answer (score 0):

Solid view is not textured view. Or Material shaded view.
If you´re using Blender 2.79 press TAB and select TEXTURED view if you need to see your textures.

Comment: Thank you, but 2 minutes ago i understood. I will answer below